# Which Ubuntu LTS version to use for MacBook Pro 9,1?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, lts, macbook-pro

I am brand new to Ubuntu and I need to dual-boot a version of Ubuntu LTS on my Mac to run some development tools are only available for Ubuntu.

It's surprising frustrating to even try to figure out which one to use.  Does the community recommend/support 16.04 for a mid-2012 MacBook Pro (9,1)?  Or should I take the safe route and go with 14.04?  I'd be happy to use 14.04 since I heard that is more stable (bigger installation base and wider driver support).

But when I try to download the image, I see either 64-bit AMD only or 32-bit for Mac. Is that the case? So should I download the 32-bit version for my MacBook?

Thank you for your advice!  Much appreciated.

Comment: I got a little carried away with my answer. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Good for you for being open to discovering the awesomeness of Linux!

---

**Since you have a beefy computer, I'd recommend Kubuntu 16.04 64-bit. For convenience, here's a [direct link](http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/).**

FYI: The 64-bit version has "AMD" in the name simply because AMD created the modern x64 architecture as we know it. I *think* Intel still leases x64 from AMD...

You **do not** need a Mac-specific image, and you **definitely** want the x64 version.

---

## Backup, backup, backup!

No matter how many people have successfully installed Ubuntu alongside OSX, there is still a very real possibility of losing everything on your hard disk, so please, do the prudent thing and make a full backup before proceeding!

---

## Note: You need to install `rEFInd` to get a boot menu on startup.

Here's a guide on how to do that, taken from the How-To-Geek:

> rEFInd is a boot manager that will allow you to choose between Mac OS
>   X, Linux, Windows, and other operating systems when you boot your
>   computer. Installing rEFInd makes the dual-boot process easier. (Some
>   older how-to’s will instruct you to use rEFIt, but it’s no longer
>   maintained. rEFInd is a currently maintained boot manager based on
>   rEFIt.)
>
> [Full-disk encryption](http://www.howtogeek.com/184675/how-to-encrypt-your-macs-system-drive-removable-devices-and-individual-files/) causes problems with rEFIt, so you’ll need to
>   disable full-disk encryption or [do some extra work](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#wde) before installing
>   rEFInd.
>
> First, visit the [rEFInd page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) and click the Download
>   button to download the latest `refind-bin-[version].zi`p file. Open a
>   Terminal window by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and, typing *Terminal*, and
>   pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag and drop the `install.sh` file from the downloaded
>   zip file into the terminal window and press Enter to run it.
>
> [image]
>
> Shut down your Mac — a full shut down, not a restart — and boot it
>   back up again. You should see the rEFInd boot manager screen.
>
> [image]

---

## Now for the actual install:

While the ISO is downloading, use Disk Utility to [partition your HDD](http://www.geek.com/apple/how-to-partition-a-mac-hard-drive-1482555/). Make sure to leave the partition you create as "Free Space". (No filesystem)

[image]

After you download the ISO, [burn it to a blank DVD](http://lifehacker.com/251758/mac-tip--how-to-burn-an-iso-or-dmg-file-to-disc).

If you'd like to burn it to a USB stick instead, see: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Next, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while hitting the power button. Continue to hold it down until you get the boot device selection menu. Then you want to choose "EFI Boot". It will show a picture of a DVD if you burned it to a DVD, and it will show a picture of a drive if you burned it to a USB stick.

[image]

After the installer loads, select the "Install Ubuntu" option, and then select "Install Alongside Mac OSX". Hopefully, it will automatically install to the partition you left as "Free Space" earlier.

[image]

After it installs, shut down and remove the installation media. Then reboot, and cross your fingers. Hopefully you'll see this:

[image]

## If after installing your Wi-Fi doesn't work:

Then you should post a new question on this site, including the version of Ubuntu you installed, whether you have a working Ethernet port, and the output of these two terminal commands:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
rfkill list all
```

And I'm sure Pilot6 or Chili555 will be glad to assist you!

Comment: Thx Android Dev!

Answer (score 0):

The 64 bit version has "AMD" in its name because AMD made the 64 bit adaptation of x86. It doesn't matter for that decision whether your computer has an Intel or an AMD CPU, it matters whether your CPU only supports 64 bit systems, only 32 bit systems, or both. Just download the 64 bit version even though it says "AMD" in the file name of the image.

It doesn't really matter what anyone recommends as long as it isn't based on hard facts because opinions and preferences very.

You should probably just download the latest LTS. That's 16.04 and you can download the 64 bit version by clicking [this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso).

If there are problems and you don't manage to solve them or already read that there are driver issues with 16.04 which there aren't with 14.04, download the 14.04 image via [this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso).

Installing Ubuntu is a matter of minutes so spend less time worrying about which version to choose and just choose the next one if you're not happy with the one you just tried.